# How to set __RequestVerificationToken retreived from Ajax call within $.ajaxprefilter?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I would like to use $.ajaxPrefilter to set the __RequestVerificationToken header, which I would like to retreive within the $.ajaxPrefilter function with an Ajax call to an API that returns an up to date __RequestVerificationToken value. It has to be asynchronous and here lies the problem. How can I make sure that the token is resolved before the original request is passed through without setting the async property to false?

I have tried to use $.ajaxPrefilter, but this only works witht the async boolean set to false. See code provided.

```
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
      filters.forEach(function(filter) {
        if (options.url.indexOf(filter) !== -1 && options.type === 'POST') {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/Rvt',
            data: null,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true
          }).done(
            function(data) {
              jqXHR.setRequestHeader('__RequestVerificationToken', data);
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

My goal is to have the __RequestVerificationToken header to be updated right before the request goes to the server, without having to set the async property to false.